# What does 's=.*/==' do in sed?

Tags: sed

I saw `sed 's=.*/=='` in context of sh script and I'm puzzled. I could not find in sed manual or web search (for `sed s=`) how `s` is used, not `s///`. Apart from `s` I see only one potential command here `=` (Print the current input line number), but in such case what the rest is doing...

Running the command in shell produces same output as input for e.g `echo 'jkfdsa=335r34'`,  whereas `echo 'jkfdsa=335r34' | sed 's/=.*/==/'` does replacement as per manual.
Also slightly modifying command to e.g. `echo 'jkfdsa=3' | sed 's798=.*/==/'` gives
`sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated 's' command`, so original should have some correct meaning. What is it?

Comment: `sed 's=.*/=='` removes all content before and '/' itself

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `=` are alternative delimiters.  These are used since the pattern contains a `/` (which is the more commonly used delimiter).  Almost any character can be used as an alternative delimiter, so `s@.*/@@` or `s_.*/__` would have meant the same thing.  With the ordinary delimiter, the `sed` expression could have been written as

```
s/.*\///
```

(the literal `/` that the expression wants to match needs to be escaped here) or, possibly more readable,

```
s/.*[/]//
```

(most characters within a `[...]` character class are literal<sup>1</sup>)

What the `sed` expression does is to substitute anything that matches `.*/` with nothing.  This will have the effect of removing everything up to and including the last `/` character on the line.  It will remove up to the *last* `/` (not the first) since `.*` does a greedy match of any sequence of any characters.

Example:

```
$ echo 'a/b/c' | sed 's/.*[/]//'
c
```

The `unterminated 's' command` error that you get when testing

```
s798=.*/==/
```

is due to `7` being used as the delimiter for the `s` command.  The expression

```
s7.*/77
```

would have worked though.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>... apart from the characters that have special meaning within `[...]` such as `^` (at the start) and `-` (when not first, second after `^`, or last). The characters `[` and `]` also needs special treatment within `[...]`, but that goes outside the scope of this question.</sub>

---

If this is used to get the filename at the end of a path in some string or shell variable, then the `basename` utility may do a better job of it (and also does the right thing if the path ends with a slash):

```
$ basename a/b/c
c
$ basename a/b/c/
c
```

Likewise, the standard shell parameter substitution `${variable##*/}` would, assuming the variable contains no newlines, be equivalent in its effect to passing the value of `$variable` through the above `sed` expression in a command substitution, but many times faster.

The variable substitution and the `basename` utility also copes with correctly handling pathnames containing newlines, which `sed` would not do (since it processes its input line by line).

Comment: Thank you, very detailed. I wonder if it's on man page somewhere, I could not find by searching for `alternative` word.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov For GNU `sed`, it is documented in the "info pages" for the `s` (substitute) command ([online link here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)).  For BSD `sed`, it's mentioned in [the manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sed#SED_FUNCTIONS), and the [POSIX spec, for `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html) also mentions this in connection to the `s` command. They may not use the wording "alternative delimiter" though.

Comment: I don't think `sed 's/.*[/]//'` is POSIX, but then I think the POSIX specification is defective in this instance.

Comment: Yes, now I see `The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command.`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh? I might have to read up on that later.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking `.*/` matches the first sequence of 0 or more _characters_, as many as possible that is followed by a `/` character. A file path on Unix generally can be any sequence of non-nul bytes which may not form valid characters, so `.*/` may not match everything up to the last `/`. For instance, on a file path like `$'St\xe9phane/donn\xe9es/index.txt'`, in a UTF-8 locale, it would match on `phane/` because those 0xe9 bytes don't form valid characters in UTF-8 (they would in iso8859-1). You would want to set the locale to C for `.` to match any byte.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, was there some standard way to match non-characters, or is reverting to the C locale the only way out?

Comment: It should be added that in sed, the first character after the command `s` determines the delimiter for the command. You can also write `sa.*/aa` or something like this. The following delimiters only have to be the same as the one directly after the command. Neither is `/` the default delimiter, nor is `=` a certain alternative. From sed's view, they are just the first after the command.

Comment: @ilkkachu, the behaviour of text utilities like `sed` is unspecified by POSIX if the input is not text. That includes sequence of bytes that don't form valid characters, input that doesn't end in newline and lines bigger than LINE_MAX. The first can be addressed with LC_ALL=C, second by adding the missing newline, 3rd can't be. as PATH_MAX is not guaranteed to be smaller than LINE_MAX, in theory you can't deal with arbitrary file paths with text utilities.

Comment: There is one character that is *not* literal within a `[...]` construct: `-`. Since this is a "beginner" question, you might want to mention that exception to the rule.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Added that. Will move it into a "footnote" though as it distracts.

Comment: `echo "$variable" | sed s=.*/==` and `echo "${variable##*/}"` are **not** equivalent. The `sed` option probably does not do what you want if `$variable` contains a newline. `sed`'s `-z` option (separate lines by `NUL` characters) might help. `basename "$variable"` seems to have similar results to `${variable##*/}`.

Comment: @8bittree Standard `sed` does not have a `-z` option, but you are otherwise correct. I will modify that bit ever so slightly.

Answer (score 12):

From https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/:

*It's a not-so-known fact that sed can use any character as separator for the "s" command.  Basically, sed takes whatever follows the "s" as the separator.*

So the slash in the middle becomes just a normal character. If I'm interpreting it correctly, your expression:

```
s=.*/==
```

could be also be written as:

```
s/.*\///
```

and explained as "remove anything before the last slash, including the slash".

Answer (score 10):

It greedily removes all contents before and `/` itself.

Example:

```
 echo "nsi/wnx/cmedwcm" | sed 's=.*/=='
```

Output :

```
cmedwcm
```

Here `=` serves as the delimiter for regex(.*/) and replacement(*null*).